# My father and my grandfather both were born in India and I born in Bangladesh, Can I get Indian citizenship or nationality?

Tags: citizenship, indian-citizens, nationality, bangladeshi-citizens

My father and my grandfather both were born in India. My father then shifted in Pakistan and after in Bangladesh. My mother is a Bangladeshi. By born I am also a Bangladeshi. My relatives on my father's side are still living in India. Now can I get Indian citizenship or nationality?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_nationality_law#Citizenship_by_birth

Comment: Did your father ever acquire any non-Indian nationality? If so, was it before or after you were born? Did your parents ever register you at an Indian consulate? How old are you now? Did you ever get a passport of any country?